# Error with Pandas Rank Across Columns Using a Dict

Tags: pandas, dictionary, rank

I used to use a piece of code to rank across columns within each category using a dict. But with the new Pandas/Python3, I am getting the following error:

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (100, 4), indices imply (100, 100)

Any suggestions or assistance is appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = dict()
d ={'A': 'Health Care', 'AA': 'Materials', 'B': 'Health Care', 'BB': 'Materials'}
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,4), index=range(0,100), columns=d.keys() )
data.groupby(d , axis = "columns").rank(axis = "columns", pct=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran that code on my machine and it worked fine, although I'm using Anaconda 3.6.4 and Pandas 0.22.0. Maybe its a version issue. Is this the correct output?

the output:

```
d = dict()
d ={'A': 'Health Care', 'AA': 'Materials', 'B': 'Health Care', 'BB': 'Materials'}
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,4), index=range(0,100), columns=d.keys() )
data.groupby(d , axis = "columns").rank(axis = "columns", pct=True)


A   AA  B   BB
0.5 1.0 1.0 0.5
1.0 0.5 0.5 1.0
0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0
0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0
0.5 1.0 1.0 0.5
1.0 0.5 0.5 1.0
1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5
0.5 1.0 1.0 0.5
0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5
```

Comment: Yes. The output is what I am looking for. I am using Pandas '0.23.0'. I suspected it is a version issue. Any suggestions on how to solve it other than downgrading?

Comment: I would try uninstalling pandas and reinstalling a certain version, if you absolutely don't want to solve this issue in the code that you have

Comment: I am open to modifying the code. Just I am not sure how what I need to do to fix the code.

Comment: I hate to use For-Loops, but I think I will have to Loop through the groups and use the .rank() function each iteration of the For-Loop.